# cleveref and titlesec, \section issues.

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, appendices, cleveref

I have some problems with `cleveref` and `titlesec`, providing a minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec} %% <-- the issue as far as i know, but i need the package
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ninjas are okay}
some text \cref{app:ninja_bkg} bla bla and \cref{app:ninja_fail}
\appendix
\chapter{ninja background}
\label{app:ninja_bkg}
ninjas originated from ???
\section{ninja fail}
\label{app:ninja_fail}
usually ninjas dont fail, but sometimes they do
\end{document}
```

where the line in the middle produces:

> some text appendix A bla bla and **section** A.1

But I want:

> some text appendix A bla bla and **appendix** A.1

If I remove the `titlesec` package everything works fine, but sadly I need it. Guessing `titlesec` redefines `\section`, but I'm not enough of a latex-hacker to fix it =/

Comment: I was just going to suggest to use `hyperref`s `\autoref` instead, but then figured out that it produces the same text output.

Comment: I'll comment this to show a minimal working solution:
Change \label{app:ninja_fail} into \label[appendix]{app:ninja_fail}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use (as described in `cleveref`'s documentation) `\crefname`, `\Crefname`, and the optional argument for the `\label` command to supply a new "type" for the sections in the appendices, ; a little example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{secinapp}{appendix}{appendices}
\Crefname{secinapp}{Appendix}{Appendices}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}\label{testchap}

\section{test section}\label{testsec}

A reference to a regular section: \cref{testsec}, and a reference to a section in appendix: \cref{testsecapp}

\appendix
\chapter{Test appendix}\label{testapp}

\section{Test section in app}\label[secinapp]{testsecapp}

\end{document}
```

The `cleveref` documentation gives a hint about using the `aliascnt` package to avoid having to use the optional argument for the new type (I haven't tested this approach, though).

Comment: That works, even though a bit cumbersome. Thanks!

Comment: What if I'm using chapters instead of sections in my appendix? What is the key I need to modify?