# cleveref and appendix packages: appendix referenced as section

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref

Using this example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{sec:1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{The second section}
\cref{sec:1} tells us something, while \cref{app:1} tells us something else!

\begin{appendices}
  \section{The first appendix}\label{app:1}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The reference `\cref` to the appendix section unfortunately references it as “section A”, rather than “appendix A”.

Is there any way to fix that?

> section 1 tells us something, while section A tells us something else!

One solution I found is this: [Create an additional `\crefname` and use it as an optional argument to `\label`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17874/cleveref-and-titlesec-section-issues/17876#17876).

Answer (score 52):

## New answer

The package `cleveref` allows one to alias different counters to other ones, and this works locally in groups.  So one solution is to add

```
\crefalias{section}{appendix}
```

just after `\begin{appendices}`.  You can do this globally using `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\crefalias{section}{appendix}}

\begin{document}

\section{The first section}
\label{sec:1}

\lipsum[2]

\section{The second section}

\Cref{sec:1} tells us something, while \cref{app:1} tells us something
else!  In \cref{app:2}, we see that this is self-contradictory.  All
is fine again in \cref{sec:3}.

\begin{appendices}
  \section{The first appendix}
  \label{app:1}
  \lipsum[2]
  \subsection{An appendix subsection}
  \label{app:2}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{appendices}

\section{The third section}
\label{sec:third-section}
\label{sec:3}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

## Old answer

The package `cleveref` provides a mechanism for this.  Introduce a new type `appsec` and set up the label name via `\crefname`; then in the appendices part use `\crefalias` to get the section type to point to the type `appsec`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\Crefname{appsec}{appendix}{appendices}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{sec:1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{The second section}
\Cref{sec:1} tells us something, while \cref{app:1} tells us something else!

\begin{appendices}
  \crefalias{section}{appsec}
  \section{The first appendix}\label{app:1}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be obvious, but just to note: if you want a lowercase (or otherwise different) prefix mid-sentence, you need to define `\Crefname` and `\crefname`

Comment: It can also be helpful in some circumstances to add additional lines at the beginning of the appendices like `\crefalias{subsection}{appsec}`, in which case references to subsections in the appendix will have the correct label as well.

Comment: `\crefname` is for defining the lowercase form of the reference name and `\Crefname` is for defining the uppercase form. It would be better to use `\crefname{appsec}{appendix}{appendices}` or `\Crefname{appsec}{Appendix}{Appendices}` in this example to fit with the intent of the `cleveref` package. The package provides the option `capitalize` for users who wish all references to be capitalized.

Comment: @RobotRaven Many thanks.  I turns out only the `\Crefname` variant respects the class option.

Comment: @OJFord Please see the new answer, which addresses this issue too.

Answer (score 1):

I managed it without using `\cleverref`'s more complicated features (`crefname`, `crefalias` or `appsec`) by using `\appendix` instead. You need to place `\cref` underneath `\appendix` for `\cref` to work out-of-the-box. You have two approaches:

1. Use `\appendix` and not `\begin{appendices}`—the table of contents won't show an "Appendices" header.

```
\appendix
\chapter{Literacy Methodologies for Non-Dominant Languages}
{\label{a1}}
...
\cref{a1}
```

[image: evidence of only "A" in the table of contents]

2. Use both `\appendix` and `\begin{appendices}`. Both "Appendices" and "A" will appear in the table of contents, albeit at the same visual hierarchy.

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
% [page] gets you a page just to announce the appendices
...
\begin{appendices}
    \appendix
    \chapter{Literacy Methodologies for Non-Dominant Languages}
    {\label{a1}}
\end{appendices}
...
\cref{a1}
```

[image: evidence of "Appendices" and "A" in the table of contents]

3. Update: Adjust the import parameters of `\appendix` to get the table of contents just right.

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
...
\begin{appendices}
    \appendix
    \chapter{Literacy Methodologies for Non-Dominant Languages}
    {\label{a1}}
\end{appendices}
...
\cref{a1}
```

[image]

Either way, the text from `\cref` will say "Appendix A".

[image: evidence that \appendix creates "Appendix A"]