# How to reference an Annex

Tags: report

How to reference an Annex (A)?

I've tried `\ref{Annex A}`, but this wouldn't work.

Comment: Do you have the Annex in your document? If so you would need a `\label{annex:a}` and then could `\ref{annex:a}` to it. Please provide [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/), if that does not help you solve the problem. Anyway, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @moewe, `\appendix \chapter{sqdjqsd\label{annex:a}}` When I `\ref{annex:a}` to the first code line I get `A` as reference, how do I please to get `[Annex A]` ?

Comment: Just a tip: We need to mark the counter (`\label{Annex A}`) somewhere in the document first and then we can use the cross-references (`\ref{Annex A}` and `\pageref{Annex A}`), please see the [`lshort`](http://ctan.org/search) manual.

Comment: I would not write `\appendix \chapter{sqdjqsd\label{annex:a}}`, but `\appendix \chapter{sqdjqsd}\label{annex:a}`, to be on the safe side. You could write `[Annex~\ref{annex:a}]`, or you could have a look at the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package (and then have maybe a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119513/35864) question). Do you want all your `\ref`'s to be enclosed in square brackets (`[]`) or just the ones to the appendix/annex?

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user3508865". It is more personal ;-)