# cleveref refers to appendix as chapter when titlesec is used

Tags: titlesec, cleveref, etoolbox

I use `titlesec` to adjust chapter headings for the `report` class (no page breaks in main report, but with page breaks in appendix). However, `cleveref` now refers to the appendix as "chapter A" instead of "appendix A". Where am I making a mess of it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% No page break for chapters
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter}{0.4em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{4em}{1em}
% Page break for appendices
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\appendix}{
  \titleclass{\chapter}{top}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{-2em}{1em}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{sec:FirstChapter}

The appendix can be found in \cref{sec:FirstAppendix}.

\chapter{Second chapter}
\label{sec:SecondChapter}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\label{sec:FirstAppendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: cleverefAppendix]

Comment: This is because cleveref and titlesec do not cooperate. Check this thread for a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119513/9632