# Appendix part of a book document

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, chapters, appendices, single-sided

The following MWE is a skeleton of the formatting I am using for the chapters, sections and appendices in my book.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[tmargin=2in, bmargin=2in, lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
\let\plainappendixpage\appendixpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendixpage}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
    \plainappendixpage
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


%====================================================================================================
% Chapter title format
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filleft\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{$\mid$}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3in}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\large\bfseries{\ensuremath{\bullet}}}
%====================================================================================================

%====================================================================================================
% Section symbol in TOC and in text
%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
%====================================================================================================


%====================================================================================================
% Header-Footer
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\ #1}}
%====================================================================================================

%====================================================================================================
% Cross-references
%
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true, 
    linktoc=all,     
    linkcolor=black, 
    citecolor=teal,
}
\usepackage{cleveref} 


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
    \chapter{First}
    \lipsum\\
    \vref{A1}
    \section{title}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Second}
    \lipsum
    \begin{appendices}
    %====================================================================================================
    % Local formatting
        \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filleft\LARGE\bfseries}{Appendix \thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{$\mid$}\hsp}{0pt}{\LARGE\bfseries}
        \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Appendix \MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{}}
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
        \crefname{chapter}{appendix}{appendices}
    %====================================================================================================

        \chapter{One}\label{A1}
        \lipsum
        \section{First section}
        \lipsum[1]
        \chapter{Two}\label{A2}
        \lipsum
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

My goals are:

> 1. The "Appendices" header in the TOC should not have a page reference.[image]
> 2. The separator page "Appendices" should be there (as it is there now) after the usual chapters without a page number on it.
> 3. The `appendices` part should behave like a (partially) one-sided document. First, like an one-sided document, the first appendix chapter should start on right (odd numbered page) and the next appendix chapters should start on the next new pages (even or odd numbered page). Secondly, the chapter marks in the header of a page should behave like a two-sided document (as it is there now, with no section mark in the header).
> 4. `\vref` to chapters in `appendices` (only) should produce the pre-string "appendix" instead of "chapter".
> 5. The formatting behaviour outside `appendices` should stay exactly how they are now.

Please help how to achieve these goals. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

> PS: (getting intrigued by [this plea](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/a-plea-to-those-who-answer-just-do-it-for-me-questions-please-edit-question-t?cb=1)), Please feel free to change the title of my question to a more meaningful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revised your MWE to give what I think you want. My changes are marked with `% PW -----`

```
% appendixprob.tex  SE 543637

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[tmargin=2in, bmargin=2in, lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix} % PW -------------------------
\usepackage[page]{appendix} % PW -----------------------------
\let\plainappendixpage\appendixpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendixpage}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
    \plainappendixpage
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


%====================================================================================================
% Chapter title format
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filleft\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{$\mid$}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3in}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\large\bfseries{\ensuremath{\bullet}}}
%====================================================================================================

%====================================================================================================
% Section symbol in TOC and in text
%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
%====================================================================================================


%====================================================================================================
% Header-Footer
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\ #1}}
%====================================================================================================

%====================================================================================================
% Cross-references
%
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true, 
    linktoc=all,     
    linkcolor=black, 
    citecolor=teal,
}
\usepackage{cleveref} 


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
    \chapter{First}
    \lipsum\\
    \vref{A1}
    \section{title}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Second}
    \lipsum
    \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries Appendices\par} % PW --------------
    %====================================================================================================
    % Local formatting
        \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filleft\LARGE\bfseries}{Appendix \thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{$\mid$}\hsp}{0pt}{\LARGE\bfseries}
        \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Appendix \MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{}}
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
        \crefname{chapter}{appendix}{appendices}
    %====================================================================================================

        \chapter{One}\label{A1}
        \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage % PW --------------------------------
        \lipsum 
        \section{First section}
        \lipsum[1]
        \chapter{Two}\label{A2}
        \lipsum
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I don't know the `\vref` command so that is up to you. With my changes you might find that you can eliminate some of your code but I'm not going there.

Comment: Thank you so much. In this particular document, I have not called `\vref` for a chapter outside the Appendices. So I have defined `\crefname` for a `chapter` as `appendix`. Though this hack does not solve the problem in general, it serves my purpose in this particular document. Thanks again for the rest of your efforts.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: You can add `\crefalias{section}{appendix}` right after `\begin{appendices}` to get your `\vref`s in order. See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121055). (Note that while `\vref` is from the `varioref` package, `cleveref` redefines it, which is why this works.)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. From the tagged answer, the following piece of code worked: `\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\crefalias{chapter}{appendix}}`. I don't know why your suggested piece didn't work.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: Sorry, it didn't work because I should've written `chapter` instead of `section`.

Comment: @Circumscribe I had corrected that. Still it didn't work. Don't know why.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: Did you compile twice? (The reference type name is written to the aux file on the first run and will only be used from the next run onward.)

Comment: @Circumscribe: Ah! It works. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.