# \addappheadtotoc as part in document

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

When using the package `appendix` together with e.g. `scrbook` class `\addappheadtotoc` uses a chapter style Appendices entry in the toc and bookmarks.

How do I change this such that the Appendices entry is raised to part level in both, toc and bookmarks?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{bookmark,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter%
\tableofcontents%

\mainmatter%
\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\appendices%

\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\backmatter%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this revised version of your MWE.

```
% appintocprob.tex SE 577653
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc,title,page]{appendix}

%\providecommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%  no change
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%     new simple version
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixtocname}%
}

\usepackage{bookmark,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter%
\tableofcontents%

\mainmatter%
\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\appendices%

\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\backmatter%

\end{document}
```

Note the redefinition of `\addappheadtotoc`. It is a very simple redefinition whereby I have used `part` instead of `chapter`. The original definition of `\addappheadttotoc` is much more complex as it deals with a number of potential cases so this redefinition is really applicable only to your use.

Comment: While this answer solves what I have asked for it doesn't reference the appendix correctly when using `\cref`, even though I considered the points made [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119513/cleveref-and-appendix-packages-appendix-referenced-as-section).

Comment: @Stefan Then please ask another question including an MWE that shows your use of `\cref` which does not appear in your above MWE.

Comment: @Stefan Someone reduced their acceptance of my answer. By any chance was it you?

Comment: It turns out that I messed up the first test I did. I now tried with a MWE and in the original document and it works fine also with your solution. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, I removed acceptance as I thought it does not work. I put it back again as it was originally. Sorry for the confusion on my end...

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for explaining what has happened. All the best for 2021

Answer (score 2):

With KOMA-Script class `scrbook` you do not need package `appendix`. You could use

```latex
\appendix
\addpart{\appendixname}
```

in the document.

Or you can define `\appendixmore` in the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}% paper=a4 and fontsize=11pt are default
\usepackage{bookmark,hyperref}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{\addpart{\appendixname}}% <- added


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\appendix% <- changed

\chapter{c}
\section{s}
\end{document}
```

Or you can redefine `\appendix`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}% paper=a4 and fontsize=11pt are default
\usepackage{bookmark,hyperref}

\newcommand*{\originalappendix}{}
\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand*{\appendix}{\originalappendix\addpart{\appendixname}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\part{p}
\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\appendix% <- changed

\chapter{c}
\section{s}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also works fine with `\crefalias{section}{appendix}` and so on.

Comment: Since the originally accepted answer also works with `\crefalias` (as I messed something up in the first place) I reverted and accepted the other answer again. Simply because he was faster in the first place and I can only accept one answer. Thanks for providing a second possibility anyways.